# How to get variable from another Python script (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, import, call

I have 2 Python 3.5 scripts, boot.py and about.py. Boot.py is located in /os, but about.py is located in /os/bin. Boot.py starts about.py with `os.system(/path/about.py)`. The problem is that about.py requires variables that are in boot.py, and i dont want to rewrite them all over again. So i need to start about.py in a way that it can read/use the variables in boot.py. If its unclear, i posted the codes down below.

boot.py:

```
#Boot.py
import os
import subprocess
import socket
import platform
import multiprocessing
import time
import datetime
from random import randint
#Create functions
def cls():
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')
#Set the variables
prj_name = 'boot.py'
prj_build = 1.01
prj_developer = 'RED'
#Bunch of print() and input() commands below
```

about.py:

```
#Somehow get the variables and functions defined in boot.py
print('This project is made by ' + prj_developer)
print('Build: ' + prj_build)
print('Launched by: ' + prj_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply import the other file.
By doing so the file will be run and the variables defined.

```
from boot import *
print('This project is made by ' + prj_developer)
print('Build: ' + prj_build)
print('Launched by: ' + prj_name)
```

I would also recommend putting all code of the other file, that shouldn't run when imported in a if statement (not necessary in this case though):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass # only run if file is executed directly (not from importing)
```

If the `boot.py` file is the directory above you would write (add a . for every parent directory):

```
from .. import boot.*
```

If the `boot.py` file is the directory above you would write (make sure to put a empty file called `__init__.py` in any subdirectories you are importing from):

```
from DIRECTORY.boot import *
```

Comment: But the about.py and boot.py are located in different directories.

Comment: Then you need to use relative imports. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python or https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: I didn't understand how do i apply it in my code :(

Comment: I cant put all the files together, in fact, im making a OS emulator, in which boot.py calls about.py using os.system(). The about.py and all the other files are located in a subdirectory /bin.

Comment: It says: SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import. I used the 'from .. import boot *' method.

Comment: @HackerGamerLV i know, i'm trying to find a fix... it might take a while

Comment: Any ideas what to do?